# The first call to CompositionContainer.GetExportedValueOrDefault takes more than 35 seconds

Tags: .net, mef

I am trying to understand what are we doing wrong in using MEF.

Here is how we initialize our container:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(bin, "*.dll").Where(file => !Excluded.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file))).ToArray();
var filesexe = Directory.GetFiles(bin, "*.exe").Where(file => !Excluded.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file))).ToArray();
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog( files.Concat(filesexe).Select(file => new AssemblyCatalog(file)));
m_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, true);
```

Given that container we call `GetExportedValueOrDefault` or `GetExportedValue` to actually resolve the root level dependencies. Although usually, they are resolved automatically through importing constructor or properties.

The application invokes the `GetExportedValueOrDefault` method at the very beginning to perform certain critical validations, failing which must abort the application right away.

Our problem is that the very first call to the `GetExportedValueOrDefault` method is now taking about 35 seconds.

We are using the standard MEF coming with .NET 4.5. The application is quite large and there are quite a lot of classes injected through MEF, but it does not seem logical to take 35 seconds.

This delay was probably building up gradually, but now it is greater than the Service Control Manager timeout for starting a windows service. So we increased the timeout, but this is not the solution we are looking for.

It is not feasible to migrate to `Microsoft.Composition` (aka MEF-2) at this moment.

Profiling with RedGate's ANTS profiler gives this:
[image]

Which gives me nothing except that there is some insane reflection going on. I do not understand from it how to proceed further. How am I to troubleshoot it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, but is creating a catalog for every file part of the problem? Have you tried a `DirectoryCatalog` instead?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. The problem is that MEF inspects each and every field, property, method in each and every type in the given assemblies. The bulk of the time is spent inside the reflection infrastructure - see the profiler snapshot. I wish I could say MEF not to inspect methods, since we do not [Import] into methods. Just skipping the method reflection would cut this startup time significantly. But MEF itself is written using the same awful patterns that it comes to resolve, so there is no way to hook into TypeCatalog, except writing our own and we are reluctant to do it.